# Select widget editable

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a widget with the code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'mywidget', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'mywidget',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.widgets.add( 'mywidget', {
            /* Basic Widget definition */
            button: "My Widget",
            template:"<div><div>Header</div><div class='mywidget_contents'></div></div>",
            editables: {
                content: {
                    selector: '.mywidget_contents'
                }
            },
            /* Initiate */
            init: function(){

                /* Move whatever was highlighted into the widget */
                var selectedHtml = editor.getSelectedHtml( true );
                if ( selectedHtml ) {
                    if ( selectedHtml.substr( 0, 1 ) === '<p>' ) {
                        this.editables.content.setHtml( selectedHtml );
                    } else {
                        this.editables.content.setHtml( '<p>' + selectedHtml + '</p>' );
                    }
                }

                /* Move the selection into it */
                // What to do here??
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

As you can see, when a user clicks the button for the widget, I move whatever is selected into the widget's editable area.

After that, I want to move the cursor to the end of that editable area. So if I highlight "Text" and then click the button, "Text" appears in the widget with the cursor at the end of it. I've tried a few different things with the `this.editables.content` variable like:
    this.editables.content.focus();
But it doesn't seem to do anything. Part of my confusion is also I'm not sure what class `this.editables.content` is an object of, it doesn't seem to be `CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.nestedEditable` because the documentation says there should be an `element` property (and from there I could probably figure it out) but when I call that it returns `undefined`.

I also tried this:

```
var sel = editor.getSelection();
if ( sel ) {
    sel.selectElement( this.editables.content );
}
```

But that just produces an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'range.checkReadOnly')

---

As an aside, I'm assume how I'm moving the selected text in is not the best way, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to play nice if the selected content is just text (in which case it needs to go into a `<p>`) or if it's already a paragraph. If anyone can recommend a better way that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once created, a widget fires [`ready`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-event-ready) and then [`focus`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-event-focus). Wait until `focus` and set the selection from code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/b3rys1hn/)):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'mywidget', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'mywidget',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.widgets.add( 'mywidget', {
            button: "My Widget",
            template:"<div><div>Header</div><div class='mywidget_contents'></div></div>",
            editables: {
                content: {
                    selector: '.mywidget_contents'
                }
            },

            init: function(){
                var selectedHtml = editor.getSelectedHtml( true );
                this.editables.content.setHtml( selectedHtml );

                this.once( 'focus', function() {
                    var range = editor.createRange();
                    range.moveToPosition( this.editables.content, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_END );
                    range.select();
                }, this );
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```